# Upload file to s3 via presigned URL 403 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, dropzone.js

I have following lambda signing code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
var s3 = new AWS.S3()

var bucketName = 'xxxx'

const {
  withStatusCode
} = require('../../utils/response.util')

const ok = withStatusCode(200, JSON.stringify)

const busboy = require('busboy')

const parseForm = (body, headers) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const contentType = headers['Content-Type'] || headers['content-type']
  const bb = new busboy({
    headers: {
      'content-type': contentType
    }
  })

  var data = {}

  bb.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
    data[fieldname] = val
  }).on('finish', () => {
    resolve(data)
  }).on('error', err => {
    reject(err)
  })

  bb.end(body)
})


exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  parseForm(event.body, event.headers).then((data) => {
    if (!data.contentType) {
      callback(new Error(`Missing contentType`))
    }

    if (!data.filePath) {
      callback(new Error(`Missing filePath`))
    }
    const key = data.filePath
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Expires: 3600,
      Key: key,
      Conditions: [
        // This depicts the ACL the file will have when uploaded
        { 'acl': 'public-read-write' },
        { 'success_action_status': '201' },
        ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', ''],
        ['starts-with', '$key', ''],
      ],
    }


    s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        callback(err)
      } else {
        callback(null, ok({
          signature: {
            'Content-Type': data.contentType,
            'acl': 'public-read-write',
            'success_action_status': '201',
            'Key': key,
            ...res.fields, // Additional fields submitted as headers to S3
          },
          postEndpoint: res.url,
        }))
      }
    })
  }, (error) => {
    callback(error)
  })
}
```

And it return sign data properly to dropzone. And then dropzone submit it to my s3 bucket, but it return Access Denied 403 error.

Here screen of sample of data that is submitted to s3 via vue-dropzone https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone.

[image: data submitted]

S3 policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::jktuploads/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Whats wrong with signing or submit that dont pass succesfully? I tried to remove all conditions section, but it make no difference

Comment: Is the error occurring from the lambda code? How are you invoking the lambda and passing the file contents to it?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya its invoked via vue-dropzone singer https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/blob/master/src/services/urlsigner.js
But as you can see from screenshot it succesfully pass sign data and there no errors in lambda.